# Create class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie to JavaScript , I know there is a way to create class in JS even if JS not support it like this :

```
function User()
{
    this.username = '';
    this.password = '';
    this.setInfo = function(username, password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    };

    this.checkLogin = function(){
        return (this.username === 'admin' && this.password === '@123');
    };
    return this;
}
```

and create an object of class User :  `var user = new User();`
By doing like this I can code with objects like Java, but should I use it popularly in real JS project ?

Comment: Javascript actually now has classes, even inheritance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: The code create an object

Comment: it's a factory because it has no inheritance, but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments so i will post here. Please follow this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

```
class NAME {code}
```

Very simple. if you want further instructions on that you can just google it. In fact googling this term: "javascript classes" gives you an answer C: